# H1 estilizado com borda central com css

Tags: html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Olá, queria colocar  uma borda da mesma maneira que está na imagem. Não sei como chama este tipo de borda, então fica difícil pesquisar.

```
<h1> Destaques </h1>
```

-------------------------------- Destaques --------------------------------

Sei que é possível fazer isto com css, pois já usei vários temas bootstrap que usam isto com css. Porém quero saber como fazer manualmente.

No caso percebi que não pode sobrepor uma imagem, pois se tiver um background-image ficaria com a letra riscada no fundo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E se tirasse o background color e colocasse transparente ficaria assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas teria que ficar assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Igual a este site aqui:  http://adtrends.com.br/sobre.php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Opa Amigo acho que o que você esta procurando é uma div para ficar em volta desse cabeçalho faz o teste, você pode colocar essa div e por o mesmo plano de fundo , tirando as bordas e posicionado ela encima da linha, e se você for usar esse titulo como link link fica até maior a área de contato.

Comment: o site de exemplo utiliza os `::before` e `::after`, utilizar o inspetor de elementos do Chrome e Firefox (botão direto > inspecionar elemento) pode ajudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer sem precisar de sobreposição é usar os `pseudo-elementos` `after` e `before`, segue o exemplo:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
h1:before,
h1:after {
  content: "";
  width: 35%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #555;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
h1:before {
  left: 0;
}
h1:after {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Meu título</h1>
```

Answer (score 4):

Amigo, não sei se você está falando da borda dos produtos, ou sobre esse HR junto ao destaques.
Mas caso seja sobre os produtos, é um simples

```
border: solid 1px;
```

Os destaques eu faria um HR normal, e colocaria o texto dentro de uma div sobrepondo o HR, usando position.

Comment: Estou falando dos destaques.

Comment: Sabe como se chama este efeito?

Comment: O Diego Souza mandou um exemplo acima: http://jsfiddle.net/btxdm6ut/

Comment: Mas, acredito que seja sobreposição de objetos.

Comment: Não é apenas sobreposição, existem várias maneiras de fazer isto. E sobreposição é apenas uma maneira de fazer. E acredito que não seja a correta pois com um fundo transparente não iria funcionar.

Answer (score 3):

Veja esse exemplo:

http://jsfiddle.net/btxdm6ut/

Com `position: absolute`.

A borda está com valor `solid`, mas se quiser colocar tracejada pode usar `dotted` ou alguma imagem e colocar como `background-image`.

---

Veja com `fieldset`.

http://jsfiddle.net/bLoz10by/1/

Comment: Tem um erro, no caso e se o fundo tiver um background image? Não teria como a letra ficar transparente.

Comment: `background-color: transparent` no H3, onde eu defini branco.

Comment: Mas na verdade não tem um erro. Eu respondi o que você perguntou. Agora é apenas um adendo.

Comment: A questão é que não pode ficar com a imagem por cima, pois daria bug caso alguém quisesse colocar um background-image.  Tendo respondido ou não, não posso aceitar a resposta pois está errada. teria que ser como este site aqui.  http://adtrends.com.br/sobre.php

No caso o que está sendo feito só funciona no fundo branco ou do fundo da mesma cor. Porém se tiver uma textura daria errado.

Comment: Então explique melhor na sua pergunta e poste uma imagem de exemplo.

Comment: Melhorei a explicação da pergunta

Comment: Adicionei um LINK a minha resposta.

Comment: Já que você respondeu primeiro, coloquei como resolvido.

Answer (score 2):

Existe um exelente tutorial sobre o assunto no seguinte link:
[Create Headings with Lines in CSS](http://jessica-eldredge.com/2014/01/26/headings-with-lines/)

Das soluções propostas, a minha referida é utilizando Flexbox:

```css
h1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
h1:before, h1:after {
  background-color: #ddd;
  content: '\a0';
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 1px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.5em;
}
h1:before {
  margin-right:10px;
}
h1:after {
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Destaques</h1>
```